# How I can add static fields to class in another file in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, static

I work with code generation in dart/flutter with annotation. I need to add static fields to the class in another generic file, but I can't find a way how to do this. I try

```
// origenal
class A extends $A {}

// another generic file
class $A {
   static const String aaa = "abc";
}
```

or

```
// origenal
class A {}

// another generic file
extension AExtension on A {
   static const String aaa = "abc";
}
```

or

```
// origenal
class A with $A {}

// another generic file
mixin $A {
   static const String aaa = "abc";
}
```

but anything from this doesn't work. when I ask `A.aaa` I have an error. Can I have any solution for this on flutter/dart?

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this way

```
import 'package:dart_console/test2.dart';

class A{}

void main(){
 print(B.aaa);
}
```

second file

```
 import 'package:dart_console/test.dart';
    
 class B extends A{
  static String aaa = 'aaa';
 }
```

Comment: static declares in a generic file, and users don't have knowledge about a generic file. in your example, we can use only `A` class. but in `A` class we don't see static `aaa`